# How to set matchMode using HttpParams angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, parameters, lazy-loading

I'm using HttpParams to set my http params for filtering table.

```
 let params = new HttpParams({
      fromObject: {
        page: event.first as number,
        size: event.rows as number,
        sortBy: 'created',
        sortOrder: event.sortOrder as number,
      },
    });

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(
      event.filters as FilterMetadata,
    )) {
      if (value.value !== null) {
        params = params.append(key, value.value);
      }
    }

    return params;
```

When I filter something in my table my http url looks like this.

```
url?page=0&size=5&sortBy=created&sortOrder=1&transactionType=Sale
```

I want to add matchMode to transactionType so it would be:

```
url?page=0&size=5&sortBy=created&sortOrder=1&transactionType:eq=Sale
```

Is there an option to do it with HttpParams? I'm also using PrimeNG tables with filtering options so I get matchMode back from LazyLoadEvent.

Comment: `matchMode` isn't standard language that every library or framework (or person on SO) will understand or have awareness of. it's clear from your question that you want to transform `transactionType` into `transactionType:eq` but it's unclear how this function or another developer should know when or why to append `:eq` or something else. but this isn't something `HttpParams` will have built in. you'll need to code it yourself either in the function somehow or before into the `FilterMetadata` object to have the keys you want.

Comment: @bryan60 Thank you for this information. It was useful.